# Difference between "take a taxi" and "get a taxi"

Tags: word-choice, differences, american-english, british-english, ambiguity

What is difference between the following sentences?

> 1. I **take** a taxi/bus/train.
> 2. I **get** a taxi/bus/train.

Comment: About 3500 miles (with the name 'Atlantic'). The expressions are largely equivalent, with 'take' / 'get' being delexical verbs (largely bleached of meaning, but used because _some_ verb is needed). The US preference is for 'take', the UK 'get' (or even 'catch' for a bus). (Actually, 'take' might just about be preferred in the UK if advice about a particular journey is being given: _'How will I get to the station by 5 am?' . . ._'Take a taxi'.)

Comment: related [catch-vs-take-a-bus-train](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53764/catch-vs-take-a-bus-train)

Answer (score 12):

In the realm of travel, to *take* something is to use it as your mode of transportation:

> **[take](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take#take_102)** (transitive) to use a particular type of transport
>
> **take a bus/train/plane/taxi etc**: *I usually take the bus to work.*

In British English, *get* is more common than *take* for this usage:

> **[get](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/get#get_134)** (transitive) (never passive) to use a particular vehicle to travel somewhere
>
> *He usually tries to get the 9.03 train.*

In American English, to *get* a taxi, etc. is to obtain its use. I might ask my hotel concierge to *Please get me a car to South Station*, or inquire of my host *Is it easier to get a cab on Lexington or Park Avenue?* Similarly, to *get a flight* is to reserve a seat on a flight, whereas to actually fly is to *take a flight*.

There are a variety of other ways to express the same— I can *catch* my transportation (e.g. *catch the Shinjuku Line*, *catch a flight*, *catch bus #42*), *ride* in/on it (e.g. *we rode the tram back to Palm Springs*), or simply go on/in/by something (e.g. *Can I reach LAX by Metrorail?*) among others. But not all of these may apply to all modes; we *fly* rather than *ride* aircraft, for example, even though we are passengers and not pilots most of the time (e.g. *We always fly Air New Zealand to Fiji*).

Answer (score 7):

The rules are different for taxis than for buses and trains.

To *get* a taxi is to secure the services of a taxi for transportation. To *take* a taxi is to ride in one. That is, you have to *get* a taxi before you can *take* a taxi:

> You'll never *get* a taxi in this neighborhood/at this time of night/in this weather
>
> We *got* a taxi at the airport and *took* it to the hotel.

On the other hand, it's pretty unusual to *get* a bus or a train (though not impossible). It's more common to *take* or *catch* a bus or train. As you can see in this ngram, the forms with "get" for buses and trains are much less common.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the US you take a taxi, not get a taxi. If you say you got a taxi, the listener would assume that you bought a taxi. If you want to go by bus, you say that you want to take the bus. Or you get on the bus and get somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

In this case take refers to the physical act of going and get to the process of acquiring. So they roughly mean the same thing, but with a different emphasis.
I call the taxi service to get (acquire) a taxi. When it comes I will take it (ride in it) to my destination.

Comment: This would benefit from a citation or reference to support your answer.  Otherwise it reads more like a comment.  Please check out the [help] and the [FAQ] for tips on answering, and welcome to EL&U.

Comment: What precisely does this add to what has already been posted on this page?