# Take the car (underground) and get the car (underground)

Tags: meaning

I know than we can say

> *let's go by car*

OR

> *let's take the car* (because it is too far to walk - and I already have the car nearby.)

But, can we say:

> *Let's get the car*

And the same with the underground. We can say:

> *Let's go by underground.*
>   *Let's take the underground.*

But, can we say:

> *Let's get the underground*

I know about that 'take' is more AE and 'get' is more BE, but I'm not sure that it is correct to use 'get' with 'underground' and 'car' in BE in the meaning 'go by'.

Comment: Related: *[Difference between “take a taxi” and “get a taxi”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144742)* and *[“Catch” vs “Take” a Bus/Train](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53764)*.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word take in, "let's take the car" is implying that you bring the car with you where you go. Get doesn't seem to connote this and thus doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: "let's take the car" is implying that you bring the car with you where you go. - Yes, I mean I already have the car where I say: Let's get the car (because it is far away to walk). So I can't say this way?

Comment: "Let's get the car" implies bringing the car to where you are now before departing. "Let's take the car" does not.  If you are already at the car there is no need to go get it.

Comment: @Selio: Brits use *take* and *get* interchangeably with *bus, train, plane, Tube, Underground, tram*, etc., partly because they're all things running to a schedule, which we can "catch, obtain". We usually *get a lift* in another's car, but *take* (in the sense of "accept") can also be used there. But we never use *get the car* in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that in AmE we use take more than get to mean *use as a means of transport*.

But, there are circumstances where each is correct and/or incorrect.

You take the subway (underground), a train, a bus, a taxi, a boat, etc..  Generally, these are situations where someone else is doing the driving.

While you are on the vehicle, you are *taking* it.  It is a continuous process.

If you say I *took my car* it means that you brought your own car somewhere, as opposed to someone else driving you.  In other words, you transported your car somewhere in the process of it transporting you.  The difference is subtle, and some might argue non-existent.

But, in AmE it sounds a bit funny to say:

> Take your car to New Jersey, I'll meet you there.

Whereas, you would definitely say

> Take the train to New Jersey, I'll meet you there.

For the first example, most would say "Drive your car to New Jersey . . ."

Now, as to get in AmE:

Get carries the implication of boarding the vehicle in question (and in most uses is interchangeable with *catch* -- *e.g.* catch a cab, etc.).

Americans get a taxi, get a bus, get a ride, etc.  But, the implication is that you get things like the train, subway, taxi, bus, etc. at a station or other point of embarkation.  In other words, once you are on said vehicle, you have already gotten it, and now you are riding in it.

If you say *get the car*, you mean, let's go walk over to it, and bring it here.  The usage is similar to that of take.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any references beyond my word as a native speaker.  The dictionary definitions are not enough to explain these nuances.

Comment: +1 particularly because I think the possibility of ***catching**, obtaining (temporary/shared use of)* the relevant type of transport vehicle is central to whether or not you can "get" it. The only one I can think of where that's not so obviously relevant is you can either *get* or *take a lift* with someone else (I'd normally use *get* there, but *take* doesn't sound particularly off to me).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oddly, we *never* get an elevator in the US.  We always take one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you mean 'get or take a lift with someone else' - to take the lift to reach up OR to ride with someone else in the car?

Comment: @Fumblefingers I totally misread that!!!!!!  Yes, we only say get a lift (get a ride).

Comment: @David: Never say never, and *only* say *usually!* Google Books [*"get the elevator to the"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22get+the+elevator+to+the%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) returns 159 hits. Granted, *take* there returns 63K hits, so it's a pretty strong preference. The UK equivalents (using ***lift***) are *get*:117 and *take*:10K, so our preference is much the same.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It was the same never as: never end a sentence with a preposition . . . You can't take it seriously.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: My assertion that it is wrong to say 'let's get the Underground' has been contested in the comments to my answer and disreputed with evidence, so my view on this should probably be disregarded.**

In British English, to use 'get' to mean 'go by' would be incorrect in both of these cases. 'Let's get the Underground' doesn't make sense, and 'let's get the car' conveys that the car needs to be collected from somewhere.

Strangely, you *can* say 'let's get the bus' and 'let's get the train'. That's very odd, and it's not something I've ever noticed before reading your question!

Comment: -1 Plenty of Londoners [*get the Underground*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22get+the+underground%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (or *get the Tube*) every day. If you can "catch" it, you can "get" it (that's why we *don't* "get the car" - we have to "take the car").

Comment: I was born in London and have lived here for most of my life. I don't recall ever hearing anybody say 'get the Underground', and to my ear it sounds very strange. I don't see what your linked-to Google search proves, as only one instance of the phrase on the first page uses it in the sense of 'travel via', and it's used in what appears to be a children's book, and does so in reference to taking the metro to 'Tsim Sha Tsui station'. I'd like to know if my Oyster card is valid for that journey :)

Comment: 568ml, I agree with FumbleFingers. I'm familiar with people saying *get the Underground*, referring to the London Underground.

Comment: 568ml: I've lived most of my 60 years within 20 miles of a Tube station, and the usage seems perfectly idiomatic to me. I admit that link wasn't actually a very good one - but 6 out of the first 7 results for [*get the Underground **to***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22get+the+underground+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) match the context under consideration.

Comment: @FumbleFingers in that case I must yield to the presence of real evidence and concede that my usage is strange and non-standard, and will edit my answer to say so. I don't want to seem abrasive, but it really does sound odd to me, as would saying 'let's catch the Underground'. I think of the Underground as a vast, complex system rather than a discrete vehicle, and in this sense it feels jarring to say that you'd 'get it' from point A to B. Just as nonsensical is to say 'take the Underground', which is exactly what I would say, so I ought to stop trying to justify myself!

Comment: 568ml: I'm reasonably well educated, but that has little bearing on my knowledge of idiomatic usages. I think one of the more crucial factors is I usually try to tailor my own "register" to that of the people I'm conversing with, and to do that successfully I particularly tend to watch out for and mimic usages that might originally have seemed "odd" to me (unless it's a non-native speaker, obviously! :). I think that by forcing myself to use "unfamiliar" forms in that way, I've ended up being more accepting of a wider range of usages than the average native speaker.

Comment: ...anyway, in light of your edit, I can no longer say your answer is significantly misleading, so I've cancelled the downvote.

Comment: Get the bus is very standard AmE.